# Jetpack compose layout changes in dialog doesn't update the size

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I've got a dialog where the user can select something and depending on the choice, the layout will be updated. The problem is that the height of the dialog is never updated to reflect the layout changes.

How to recompose the dialog to make the layout fit in the dialog?

Example:

```
@Composable
fun AlertDialogTest() {
    var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
    var showExtra by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
    Button(onClick = { showDialog = true }) {
        Text("Open dialog")
    }
    if (showDialog) {
        AlertDialog(
            text = {
                Column { Button(onClick = {showExtra = true}) {
                        Text ("Show rest of dialog")
                    }
                    if (showExtra) {
                        Text("More text", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5)
                        Text("Even more text", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5)
                    }
                }
            },
            confirmButton = { TextButton(onClick = { showDialog = false }) {
                Text("Close")
            }},
            onDismissRequest = {showDialog = false},
        )
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/68818540/7972699

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194911971?pli=1

Comment: Still hasn't been fixed as of `compose:1.2.0`

Answer (score 9):

I've also faced the same issue, and found the solution for a longer text or other contents in `Jetpack Compose Alert Dialog`

```
 AlertDialog(
    onDismissRequest = { },
    properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false),
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(28.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight(),
    title = null,
    text = {
           // Your alert dialog content
    },confirmButton = {
        TextButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text(text = "OK")
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, I also solve it with .wrapContentHeight().

Comment: `wrapContentHeight()` doesn't do anything. What actually makes it work is `properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)`

Answer (score 2):

It did work as expected for me in `beta08`. Then, after upgrate to `rc02` it stopped working - popup dialogs, drop down menus (basicaly all elements that are backed by platform windows) stopped resizing properly on content size change. And indeed I've found a bug for it - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194911971. And for now I, sadly, haven't found a workaround, so we better wait until it's fixed.

UPD.
As is commented in aforementioned issue, there is a workaround. Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818202/animatedvisibility-doesnt-expand-height-in-dialog-in-jetpack-compose/68818540#68818540).

Answer (score 1):

Another possible workaround consists in forcing recomposition of the dialogue when data changes: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221643630#comment8

Comment: It wasn't the workaround that helped me but rather the update mentioned later. Thanks for the link.