# AnimatedVisibility Doesn't Expand Height In Dialog in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

So I have this composable in my project ...

```
 @Composable
 private fun ShowDialog() {
        var showText by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

        val text = if (showText) {
            "Hide Text"
        } else {
            "Show Text"
        }

        Dialog(onDismissRequest = { }) {
            Card(modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)) {
                Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)) {
                    AnimatedVisibility(visible = showText) {
                        Text(
                           text = "Here is the show text sample",
                           modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
                           style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                           color= Color.Black
                        )
                    }

                    Button(onClick = { showText = !showText }) {
                        Text(text = text)
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

If you have gone through the code, you might get what it is supposed to do. i.e it is basically a dialog with one text and a button below it. When the user clicks on a button the text above the button will toggle its visibility.

But the problem with the code is, When I click on the button, the text appears but the button gets invisible in other words the text takes the space and pushes a button to below. But yet the container in this case card or the column doesn't expand its height.

Is it supposed to work like that ? Or is this a bug?

I tried `animateContentSize()` on `Column` and `Card` but it didn't work. And checked similar questions on StackOverflow but didn't found any useful information.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194911971

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thanks for the link... since this is assigned ... is there any alternative way to overcome this? any tips on this would be helpful

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I found a way to fix this check my answer once any other suggestions are also better...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Luckily, I found a temporary working answer for this problem,

What we need to use is just pass `DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)` as properties `parameter` for dialog. This will make the dialog to resizable like this

```
    @Composable
    private fun ShowDialog() {
        var showText by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

        val text = if (showText) {
            "Hide Text"
        } else {
            "Show Text"
        }

        Dialog(
            onDismissRequest = { },
            properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)
        ) {
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(15.dp)
                    .wrapContentWidth()
                    .animateContentSize()
            ) {
                Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp).fillMaxWidth(1f)) {

                    AnimatedVisibility(visible = showText) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Sample",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(5.dp)
                                .fillMaxWidth(1f),
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                            color = Color.Black
                        )
                    }
                    Button(onClick = { showText = !showText }) {
                        Text(text = text)
                    }


                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Caution: It uses `@ExperimentalComposeUiApi`

> This API is experimental and is likely to change in the future.

Comment: idk understand why this works to allow the height to be dynamic but thank you for sharing the answer; you're a saint

Comment: How do I keep the default width and leave it animatable? Thanks.

Comment: @MarkDelphi I don't think that's possible

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: @c-an which version of compose you are using ?

Comment: @AgentP I am using bom 2023.01.00 which is 1.4.3.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to have the default platform width and cannot use `usePlatformDefaultWidth = false`, here is another workaround until the [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221643630) is fixed:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DynamicHeightDialog(
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    properties: DialogProperties = DialogProperties(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
        properties = properties,
    ) {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .clickable(
                    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                    indication = null,
                    onClick = onDismissRequest,
                )
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var opened by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }
Switch(
    checked = opened,
    onCheckedChange = { opened = it },
)
if (opened) {
    DynamicHeightDialog(
        onDismissRequest = {
            opened = false
        }
    ) {
        Surface {
            Column() {
                var expanded by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
                val height by animateDpAsState(if (expanded) 100.dp else 20.dp)
                Switch(
                    checked = expanded,
                    onCheckedChange = { expanded = it },
                )
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(height)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, this is a legit workaround - wrap your content in a Box with fillMaxSize() (which forces the "dialog" to be as large as it can be) and clickable (to allow the user to click "outside" the dialog contents to dismiss the dialog) modifiers.

Comment: @Tom thanks for your upvote =) I also don't understand why some people put downvotes without leaving an explanatory comment. Personally, I find this solution more suitable for my own case

Comment: It's better for mine too, `usePlatformDefaultWidth=false` actually makes my dialog content automatically slide in from the top left corner which isn't ideal!  The solutions are also just as 'hacky' as the other, but `usePlatformDefaultWidth` feels a bit more prone to the whims of internal compose platform changes.

Comment: Especially with https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194911971 slated for fixing...

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be fixed by https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221643630.

The dialog resizes as expected (tested with `androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialog`).