# Creating a Dialog in compose doesn't display correctly

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following `Dialog` where the user will enter an email address. If the email is invalid it will display a error message below. But for some reason when I show the error message it seems to cut off the button.

[image]

I have code in the Dialog that will show or hide the error message.

```
if(!isEmailVerifiedSuccess) {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        text = stringResource(R.string.email_verify_failed),
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
    )
}
```

It seems the dialog doesn't make room and pushes the button down. However, in the previews it looks fine.

```
fun AddVisitorDialog(
    email: String,
    isEmailVerifiedSuccess: Boolean,
    onEmailChanged: (email: String) -> Unit,
    onDialogClose: () -> Unit,
    isValidInput: Boolean,
    onAddButtonClicked: (email: String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    Dialog(onDismissRequest = { onDialogClose() }) {
        Column(
            modifier = modifier,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {

            IconButton(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.End),
                onClick = {
                    onDialogClose()
                }) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.close),
                    contentDescription = "close button"
                )
            }

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                text = stringResource(R.string.add_visitor),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.agendaSubTitleHeaderColor
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))

            UserInputTextField(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                isInputValid = isValidInput,
                inputValue = email,
                placeholderText = stringResource(id = R.string.email_address),
                onInputChange = { newEmail ->
                    onEmailChanged(newEmail)
                }
            )

            if(!isEmailVerifiedSuccess) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    text = stringResource(R.string.email_verify_failed),
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
                )
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))

            TaskButton(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                buttonText = stringResource(R.string.add),
                onButtonClick = {
                    onAddButtonClicked(email)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to check this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818202/animatedvisibility-doesnt-expand-height-in-dialog-in-jetpack-compose

Answer (score 0):

at this time you can change the code for hiding / showing error message in dialog to

```
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    text = if(!isEmailVerifiedSuccess) stringResource(R.string.email_verify_failed) else "",
    fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
    fontSize = 16.sp,
    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
)
```

`Text` composable's value change based on the `isEmailVerifiedSucess`. since there is no more height issuse.